# Error deploying Maven web project to Wildfly 9

Tags: java, maven, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-9

I'm trying to run a maven web project.
I created a maven web project (web archetype) using intellij.
Here's what my POM looks like

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.samako</groupId>
    <artifactId>ripple</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>ripple Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>ripple</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Alpha4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                    <username>USER_NAME</username>
                    <password>MY_PASS</password>
                    <port>9990</port>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                    <username>USER_NAME</username>
                    <password>MY_PASS</password>
                    <port>9990</port>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jvnet-nexus-releases</id>
            <name>jvnet-nexus-releases</name>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
            <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

I launched the wildfly 9 server in standalone mode in a terminal tried to deploy the app using:

`mvn -q wildfly:deploy`

It fails with the following error:

```
Dec 07, 2015 2:11:50 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.7.GA
Dec 07, 2015 2:11:50 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.7.GA
Dec 07, 2015 2:11:50 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.12.GA
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jboss.as.plugins:jboss-as-maven-plugin:7.7.Final:deploy (default) on project ripple: Could not execute goal deploy on /Users/user/Desktop/RippleWeb/target/ripple.war. Reason: I/O Error could not execute operation '{
[ERROR] "operation" => "read-attribute",
[ERROR] "address" => [],
[ERROR] "name" => "launch-type"
[ERROR] }': java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9990. The connection timed out
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Would appreciate any help in figuring out how to solve this, thanks :)

Comment: can you access `http://localhost:9990` from a browser? Is wildfly running on the same machine as maven or is it running on another machine that you access through a VPN/SSH tunnel/Virtual machine manager etc.?

Comment: @assylias yes I can access wildfly. It's running locally

Comment: I took out the maven jboss-as plugin and it works fine now